# Comparar registros duplicados no banco de dados com PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando fazer um condição que impeça de salvar o mesmo nome de login de outro usuário já registrado.

```
$login_fail=("SELECT DISTINCT $login FROM login");

        if(empty($nome)){
            $errMSG = "Por favor Insira o nome";
        }

        else if($login==$login_fail){
            $errMSG = "Por favor Insira outro login";
        }
```

Estou aprendendo a usar o distinct e gostária de saber qual melhor maneira de comparar informações repetidas que já estão no banco de dados

Comment: Já pensou em criar uma chave primária ou declarar o campo como único em sua tabela?

Comment: Resolvi fazendo um consulta com where

`$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login='$login'");
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $errMSG = "Por favor Insira um login diferente";
        }`

Answer (score 0):

> Estou tentando fazer um condição que impeça de salvar o mesmo nome de login de outro usuário já registrado.

Sua pergunta não tem relação com o problema em si, porque sua solução é problemática e não resolve o que quer.

Mesmo que sua ideia funcionasse, ele ainda apresenta um problema de [race-condition](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_corrida).

---

A solução para o seu caso é utilizar o UNIQUE, adicione o INDEX de UNIQUE na coluna em que não quer que repita:

```
ALTER TABLE usuario ADD UNIQUE (login)
```

Isso irá prevenir que haja dois dados com o mesmo valor para a coluna de `login` na tabela de `usuario`. A exceção a regra é valores nulos, o valor nulo pode repetir, mesmo com o unique, desde que a coluna permita valores nulos. Portanto, o `login` não pode ter nulo habilitado.

---

Uma vez que você possui o UNIQUE, basta que faça o insert normalmente:

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario VALUES [...] ");
```

A execução irá falhar se houver dados duplicados, então poderia simplesmente usar o `rows_affected` e verificar se ele é maior do que zero.

*O código do erro é `1062` por duplicidade. Então se quiser distinguir um erro de outro (por exemplo, erro porque excedeu o limite do campo ou porque está publicado) pode utilizar o `$mysqli->errno` (ou equivalente) e comparar se o erro foi por causa da duplicidade ou não.*

---